# Installation hangs after Installation Type Screen

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, freeze, 20.04

My PC freezes after Installation after Installation Type Screen.
I am able to go through the preliminary steps but when I it "Install now" (or at an earlier step sometimes), my machine just freezes.

I've downloaded the 20.04 LTS and tried to install on an Asus ROG G20 Intel Core i7 12GB 1TB Nvidia GTX950 (not 100% sure about the graphic card but it's Nvidia for sure).

I first tried to install PoP_OS but that didn't work out (machine would not reboot after install) so I reverted back to Ubuntu. I can still access the UEFI BIOS utility.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated!

Best,
J

Comment: Hey, thanks for this but sadly no - the more I try the earlier the installation actually freezes...! :(

Answer (score 0):

After 20 or so attempts, I went happy-go-lucky on this one as there was not many alternatives and, quite shockingly, something seems to have worked.

First I switched off the safe boot mode on my BIOS, installed Mint 19.3 on compatibility mode and that seems to have done the trick...

So far, so good!